# Cannot use two processes to stream to database with SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, multiprocessing

I have two `while True` loops, each reads from an external API for some data.

```py
    db = Database(env='dev')

    aStream = AStream(db)
    proc1 = Process(target=aStream.stream_a_to_db())
    proc1.start()

    bStream = BStream(db)
    proc2 = Process(target=bStream.stream_b_to_db())
    proc2.start()
```

My `Database` class is as follows

```py
class Database:
    def __init__(self, env='dev'):
        """DB setup"""
        self.db_url = self._set_db_url_by_env(env)
        self.engine = create_engine(self.db_url, echo=True)

    def create_db_session(self):
        # Create all tables that do not already exist
        Base.metadata.create_all(self.engine, Base.metadata.tables.values(), checkfirst=True)
        # SqlAlchemy :: Session setup
        Session = sessionmaker(bind=self.engine)
        # SqlAlchemy :: Starts a session
        return Session()
```

I don't understand the result of running this code. It runs whichever is first, i.e. if I put `proc2` before `proc1`, `proc2` stream to db is the only one that runs.

I tried two things.

1. Use dummy functions instead the the actual stream.

```
def func1():
    print("func1 up and running.")

def func2():
    print("func2 up and running.")

proc1 = Process(target=func1)
proc1.start()


proc2 = Process(target=func2)
proc2.start()
```

This runs as expected, both `func1` and `func2` are running and printing.

2. Just move `bStream` to a separate python file and manually run two files, `python a_stream.py` and `python b_stream.py` in two terminal tabs without any change to other code. They each runs fine, both streaming data to db with no problem.

Basically my goal is not to have two scripts and manually run them both, but just have one with two processes. What is the right way to do this? It must have something to do with the way SQLAlchemy engine / session works. I'm new to SQLAlchemy. Appreciate any help here!

Comment: what database are you using?

Comment: SQLite for dev and Postgres for production. Both are exhibiting same behavior, so I think it's related to SQLAlchemy

Comment: SQLite should not support concurrent writes, so it is by design in this case. Can you make a minimally reproducible example for Postgres?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per [the docs](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/connections.html):

> For a multiple-process application that uses the os.fork system call, or for example the Python multiprocessing module, it’s usually required that a separate Engine be used for each child process. This is because the Engine maintains a reference to a connection pool that ultimately references DBAPI connections - these tend to not be portable across process boundaries. An Engine that is configured not to use pooling (which is achieved via the usage of NullPool) does not have this requirement.

Therefore, instead of creating the Engine in the main process and passing it to both subprocesses,
create a new Engine in each subprocess:

```
def worker(Stream, methodname):
    db = Database(env='dev')
    stream = Stream(db)
    getattr(stream, methodname)()

args = [(AStream, 'stream_a_to_db'), (BStream, 'stream_b_to_db')]
procs = [Process(target=worker, args=a) for a in args]
for proc in procs:
    proc.start()
for proc in procs:
    proc.join()
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer! This worked! Needed to go back and study the doc more about multiprocessing with SQLAlchemy.